# How to make my python code request a URL and scrape information as per need from the webpage

Tags: python, html, socks

I am using a simple python code to try and fetch a URL and scrape out all the other URLs mentioned in every webpage(all html sub-pages if any under the home/root page) of that URL. Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import re
import socks
import socket

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.python.org')

#connect to a URL
try: 
   website = urllib2.urlopen(req)

except urllib2.URLError as e:
   print "Error Reason:" ,e.reason   

else:
   #read html code
   html = website.read()
   #use re.findall to get all the links
   links = re.findall('"((http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', html)
   print links
```

Right now I am getting a simple error where the module socks is not recognized. I figured out I have to copy the "socks.py" in the correct path under Python's lib/site-packages directory.

I've added the socks module to my code, as my python script was not otherwise able to connect to the url `http://www.python.org`. My question is am I using the `socks` correctly ?

Also will my script take care of all the webpages under the root url ? as I want to scrape all `urls` from all such webpages under the root URL.

Also how can I check what would be the `port` to mention in `setdefaultproxy` line of my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use BeautifulSoup for Webscraping purpose. Below is the code for it with a lot more simpler method.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get("http://www.python.org")
c=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

anchor_list=[a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if a.text.strip()]

print(anchor_list)
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: It says `ImportError: No module named requests`. Is it an in-built module with Python2.7.3 ?

Comment: requests is not a built in module of python,so you need to install it explicitly.. try `pip install requests`

Comment: Thanks , It works now. anchor_list returns a list of sub-urls from the main url. Do you have link to detail documentation of `BeautifulSoup` and its methods.

Comment: Please go through the link below to learn  more [link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)